# Condensing if statements with multiples of same comparison operator in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to condense this code to a simpler form or another way to do this same thing?

```
if h == 0:
    day = 'Saturday'
elif h == 1:
    day = 'Sunday'
elif h == 2:
    day = 'Monday'
elif h == 3:
    day = 'Tuesday'
elif h == 4:
    day = 'Wednesday'
elif h == 5:
    day = 'Thursday'
else:
    day = 'Friday'

print('Day of the week is', day)
```

Comment: you could make a list or dictionary then get the day based on `h` fairly quickly without `if..elif..else` statements

Answer (score 5):

You can use a dictionary:

```
days= {
     0:'Saturday',
     1:'Sunday',
     2:'Monday',
     3:'Tuesday',
     4:'Wednesday',
     5:'Thursday'}

print(days.get(h,'Friday'))
```

The advantage of using `dict.get` method is that you can pass a default value to it which will be return if the key doesn't exist in dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Create the list

```
days = ('Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')

day = days[h]
print('Day of the week is', day)
```

Comment: I think this is preferable to the dictionary solution in this case, for a simple ordered list